# Css for .FileUpload button

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, button

I would like to apply this css on my .FileUpload button , but It only works on IE and not on Chrome and I still don't know what is wrong with it. Someone as got an idea ?

Thanks for helping

```
.FileUpload
{
 width: 90px;
float: left;
color: black;
font-family: Segoe UI,Arial, Sans-Serif;
border: 1px solid #C7D2D8;
height: 30px;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;
background: white;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 540px;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px 0;
letter-spacing: -1;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: How does it fail for Chrome?  What is it? (I'd assume it's an <input type="file"> but you never know.)

Comment: Actually it's a  <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible to style an `<input type="file">`, for all browsers. But you could replace the upload-field with javascript and the replacement can by styled as much as you want.

You'll get an example of such a replacement script in [this blog entry](http://the-echoplex.net/log/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-control-using-css-and-javascript).

Comment: The thing is that it's working on IE , and not on Chrome , isn'it weird ?

Comment: Not really. That different browsers interpret the same style definition differently is not weird! ;-)

Comment: But I cant use this Input Type File , because I am using method and properties from the FileUpload component .=(

Comment: The output is normal HTML, isn't it? There doesn't exists any other html tags to upload files, except `<input type="file" />`.

Comment: Yes, this is the server side programming language, and what is the output? XML/XSLT? I guess it is HTML!

Comment: You could post an output example to avoid any confusions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using jquery instead, this would be cross browser compatable then, more info here > http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#default
either that or there are several examples here on different methods of achieving what you want http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/26/20-awesome-jquery-enhanced-css-button-techniques/